# Branch coverage not visible on SonarQube dashboard

Tags: sonarqube

I am using SonarQube 3.7.3 and facing a strange issue. I have set-up a single dashboard which is used for all the sonar project. The issue is that I am not able to see branch coverage metrics in one specific project when same in visible on other projects on same sonar instance. Can you let me know what could be possible issue.

I can not attach image showing same. Same images could be viewed on http://sonarqube.15.x6.nabble.com/Branch-coverage-not-visible-in-a-project-though-it-is-visible-in-other-project-td5035725.html

The SonarQube forum is not active now and thus not getting any reply.

Comment: What is the code language of this project and what are you using to generate the coverage report (e.g. cobertura, jacoco, opencover, etc)?

Comment: Code language is java. tool is jacoco (essentially what sonarcube uses by default). The branch coverage link is coming fine for other projects except for this. All my projects are hosted on same sonarcube instance and all of them share the same sonar dashboard.

Comment: SQ 3.7.3 is pretty old, it might be a bug. Can you upgrade to more recent versions?

Answer (score 2):

Hit the same basic problem with Sonarqube 5.0.1 - two projects in same Sonar instance, one reports branch coverage, the other does not.  I *almost* updated as the above answer suggested, but was able to fix it without doing so.

Here are the two things I had to do in case it helps others:

1. In my pom.xml file, I was missing a sonar.scm.provider property.  Adding that removed a sonar-maven-plugin warning that may or may not be related.

   A closer read of the sonar-maven-plugin also revealed that sonar couldn't parse some of the Java code.  Conveniently, it dumps the block of text that it puked on so shouldn't be too hard to find.  For me, this was because I had done "Object varName []" instead of "Object[] varName" - both are legal Java, but Sonar only likes the latter.

Fixing those two issues, I was able to get the "Condition Coverage" to show up.

Good luck.